# check box selected on page load

Tags: javascript, php

I've got a product item page that should have the first of four weight options selected when the page loads using JavaScript.

It was working fine but now doesn't seem to work after a few changes to the page design.

```js
    $( document ).ready( function () {
       var licnt = $( '#product-nav' ).length;
       for ( var n = 1; n <= licnt; n++ ) {
        $( '#price_' + n ).prop( 'checked', true );
        var pric = document.getElementById( "price_" + n ).value;
        document.getElementById( "prices_" + n ).innerHTML = "<?php echo $currency; ?>" + pric;
        $( '.weightval_' + n ).val( "0.50" );
       }
      } );
    
      function outputValue( item ) {
       var pid = item.getAttribute( "id" );
       var splitid = pid.split( "_" );
       document.getElementById( "prices_" + splitid[ 1 ] ).innerHTML = "<?php echo $currency; ?>" + item.value;
       var wght = item.getAttribute( "wght" );
       $( '.weightval_' + splitid[ 1 ] ).val( wght );
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
     <div id="product-nav">
     <div class="child">
      <div id="prices_$i" class="price"></div>
     <div id="weight-select" class="select">
     <fieldset style="border: 0;">
     <label>
          <input type="radio" name="price" value="<?php echo $obj->price_1 ?>" id="price_$i" wght="<?php echo $obj->weight_1 ?>" wghtid="weight_1" onChange="outputValue(this)" >
          <div>500g</div></label>
          <input type="hidden" name="weight" value="" id="weight_$i" class="weightval_$i">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="price" value="<?php echo $obj->price_2 ?>" id="price_$i" wght="<?php echo $obj->weight_2 ?>" wghtid="weight_2" onChange="outputValue(this)">
          <div>1kg</div></label>
          <input type="hidden" name="weight" value="" id="weight_$i" class="weightval_$i" >
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="price" value="<?php echo $obj->price_3 ?>" id="price_$i" wght="<?php echo $obj->weight_3 ?>" wghtid="weight_3" onChange="outputValue(this)">
          <div>5kg</div></label>
          <input type="hidden" name="weight" value="" id="weight_$i" class="weightval_$i" >
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="price" value="<?php echo $obj->price_4 ?>" id="price_$i" wght="<?php echo $obj->weight_4 ?>" wghtid="weight_4" onChange="outputValue(this)">
          <div>10kg</div></label>
          <input type="hidden" name="weight" value="" id="weight_$i" class="weightval_$i">
     <label>
      <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $obj->product_code ?>" value="" />
     </label>
     </fieldset>
     <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="<?php echo $obj->product_code ?>" />
     <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
     <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php echo $current_url ?>" />
     </div>
     <div class="qty">
      <input type="button" value="–" class="qtyminus" field="product_qty" />
        <input type="text" name="product_qty" value="1" class="qty-textbox" style="margin-bottom: 0px !important"/>
        <input type="button" value="+" class="qtyplus" field="product_qty" />
      </div>
      <div class="add">
       <input type="submit" value="ADD" class="add-cart">
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: *doesn't seem to work* What does that mean?

Comment: You're not really trying to use `<?php echo $currency; ?>` in JavaScript, right? Is that JavaScript parsed by PHP before being sent to the client?

Comment: @jdgregson of course not an elegant way of handling things, but why not?

Comment: Lol that echo is weird but strangely enough this things works..so that's not the issue.

Comment: @jdgregson its the same file he is including the script if that file has a `.php` extension it is correct although not that clean

Comment: @Rüzgar When I first saw it I though he was trying to spit `<?php echo $currency; ?>` into the HTML itself and expect it to be turned into a value client-side. But then I realized it was being parsed through PHP before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

from the following line in your js

```
var pric = document.getElementById("price_" + n).value;
```

and that is because you are not parsing the input `id` attribute correctly the variable `$i` you have used is like

```
id="price_$i"
```

whereas it should be

```
id="price_<?=$i?>"
```

Your input should look like this

```
<input type="radio" name="price" value="<?php echo $obj->price_1 ?>" id="price_<?=$i?>" wght="<?php echo $obj->weight_1 ?>" wghtid="weight_1" onChange="outputValue(this)" >
```

You might need to look where this `$i` is coming from and it will work

Also, you have the same mistake with the `inputs` having

```
<input type="hidden" name="weight" value="" id="weight_$i" class="weightval_$i">
```

they should be like

```
<input type="hidden" name="weight" value="" id="weight_<?=$i?>" class="weightval_<?=$i?>">
```